# Android Facebook SDK login button only working on one phone

Tags: android, android-facebook

So i've got a `LoginActivity` that has the facebook `LoginButton`. It works perfectly fine with my development phone with or without the facebook application.

However, for my emulator device or for my beta testers when the login button is clicked it allows you to login and then once you've logged in, the phone simply goes back to the home screen instead of my app. It seems like the `FacebookActivity` doesn't transition back to my `LoginActivity`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("LOGIN", "We got here 123");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("LOGIN", "We got here");
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So when I am running the app on my phone, `onActivityResult` is called and everything works perfectly.

When I run it on my emulator or my beta tester's phones, `onActivityResult` is not even being called. After successfully logging in, my app is simply put in the background and the home screen is shown.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Is there a way to track errors on facebook's side?

At this point, I'm not sure exactly what's wrong.

Comment: It's a common thing to have your development version working on your own device but not on others. Download GennyMotion, run an emulator and debug your app. I believe there is an exception thrown and ignored somewhere in the code. Come back with more information

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, only my login credentials worked. The solution was to enable/ make public your project in the Facebook developer site. You may want to check for it. [image: Enabled project shows a "online" symbol]

Comment: Seems like this is not the issue :( 

My app is live and available to all users as well. 

Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Oh...Have you also tried adding release key under your project in Facebook developer site and then signed the release-apk? (i.e it would have both debug and release keys in the developer site)